# Printer Print Size

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I set the printing size (width and height) by code without showing a dialog?

Comment: Are you doing the printing manually (using `Printer.BeginDoc` etc.) or are you using a `TRichEdit` for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "printing size"?

Comment: Printing size of what? Please add more detail to your question so we have an idea of what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) documentation for [GetPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144911(VS.85).aspx) and [SetPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145082(v=VS.85).aspx). You can find basic examples of their use in Delphi [here](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0019.htm) and [here](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0020.htm). The second example has specific code for setting paper size, which I've provided below.

```
procedure SetPrinterSettings(FPrinter: TPrinter);
var
  FDevice: PChar;
  FDriver: PChar;
  FPort: PChar;
  DeviceMode: THandle;
  DevMode: PDeviceMode;
begin
  {to get a current printer settings}
  FPrinter.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);
  {lock a printer device}
  DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);

  {set a paper size as A4-Transverse}
  if ((DevMode^.dmFields and DM_PAPERSIZE) = DM_PAPERSIZE) then
  begin
    DevMode^.dmFields := DevMode^.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE;
    DevMode^.dmPaperSize := DMPAPER_A4_TRANSVERSE;
  end;

  {set a paper source as Tractor bin}
  if  ((DevMode^.dmFields and DM_DEFAULTSOURCE) = DM_DEFAULTSOURCE) then
  begin
    DevMode^.dmFields := DevMode^.dmFields or DM_DEFAULTSOURCE;
    DevMode^.dmDefaultSource := DMBIN_TRACTOR;
  end;

  {set a Landscape orientation}
  if  ((DevMode^.dmFields and DM_ORIENTATION) = DM_ORIENTATION) then
  begin
    DevMode^.dmFields := DevMode^.dmFields or DM_ORIENTATION;
    DevMode^.dmOrientation := DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
  end;

  {set a printer settings}
  FPrinter.SetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);

  {unlock a device}
  GlobalUnlock(DeviceMode);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

From your comments to other answers, it seems like you want to **select the type of paper** (A4, Legal, etc) - is that right?

[This page](http://mc-computing.com/languages/Delphi/Printing.html) states that to select the paper type, you need to use the `Printer.GetPrinter` function to get a device handle for the printer, then use `GlobalLock` to get a pointer you can access, cast to a PDeviceMode.  There is then a `PaperSize` member of the `TDeviceMode` that pointer points to which can be A4, legal, etc.

This was all just turned up via Google.  [Scroll to 'Printer Properties' on this page](http://mc-computing.com/languages/Delphi/Printing.html) for where I got this info.  This page mentions [changing the tray](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1079747&page=5) too.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. They were so useful. About my question: Sorry if i had a bad writing or question. I mean define paper size by writing print size. as YOU told define paper like A4 or etc (all of them have defined size in width and height (A4 is 210 mm in 270 mm)). I want to customize them via code for my program. This can be done by "PageSetupDialog"  dialog (Dialogs component tab -> PageSetupDialog component) but i want to set it up via direct code. Hope i was clear enough. Thank you again for you answer and sorry again if im not clear enough.

Comment: @Armin - The second Delphi example in [Ken's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864060/printer-print-size/3867666#3867666) shows how to set the paper size to A4. You'd adapt the example: set `dmPaperSize` to 0 and `dmPaperLength` and `dmPaperWidth` to your liking. Read [DEVMODE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see how these members work. (I'm not sure if all printers would comply to any arbitrary setting though..)

Comment: No worries, Armin - glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one little piece that helps get the font size correct:

```
Printer.Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch:=GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Canvas.Handle,LOGPIXELSY);
```

Comment: @Armin: Then perhaps you should more clearly state what you *do* want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to alter the margins, this is easy, but depends on how you print.

If you are printing manually (using `Printer.BeginDoc` etc.), then you simply draw on the priter's canvas further from the edges! If you are printing using a `TRichEdit`, you can change the `PageRect` property.